# Cut column from list

Tags: command-line

How can I  cut second column from the following list from terminal?

```
56    267  
57    235  
58    255  
59    283
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the data is in a file called test.txt, `awk '{ print $1 }' test.txt` will do it.

Comment: This is for first column.

Comment: You'll want `awk '{ print $2 }' file.txt` instead, to get the 2nd column.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But the way I read the question I thought OP wanted to retain the first column.

Answer (score 2):

If the space between columns is a `Tab` character, then

```
cut -f 2
```

will do what you want. If they are spaces, then compress them to a single tab first:

```
tr -s \  \\t | cut -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/\t/g" filename | cut -f2
```

First command (`sed`) will replace all whitespace characters with one tab, and the result will be passed to the second command (`cut`) which will select the second field from each line.

See [`man cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) and [`man sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

If your data was separated with a comma then your operation will be a lot easier:

```
kmcet@ubuntu:~$ cat data.txt
123,456
123,789
123,567
```

```
kmcet@ubuntu:~$ cut -d, -f1,1  data.txt
123
123
123
```